# Translating requests per second into concurrent users

Tags: performance-testing

We're building a web service that needs to handle about 200 requests per second. But most popular load testing tools talk about running a load test with a certain number of "concurrent users".

Could anyone tell me how do I translate my requirement of "200 requests per second" into "number of concurrent users"? I'm new to the field of performance testing and from all that I've read so far, this aspect of it doesn't get addressed.

Thanks
Vimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This translation is not possible in the general case. The problem is that a user can make multiple requests. If each user could make exactly one request (e.g. your service is completely stateless), and each request would take exactly a second, your number of concurrent users *may* coincide with the number of requests per seconds.

Otherwise (and those are big assumptions to make), you either track users while logging and get the respective numbers from the log or you add your assumptions into the requirements for the load test.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My users are stateless and the response of the webserver is much less than a second... Now I'll try to explain this to management... :)